# How to calculate the probability of an event that can happen in different ways with different probabilities

Tags: probability

> [image: A visual representation of the situation]

(Please check the picture above to understand the question, I sensorily apologize for my lack of proper language.)

Imagine that you are in a Casino, your eyes stumble upon this basic game where a metal ball
falls and bounces from some obstacles to end up in one of four holes, but there is a wall to
the left of one of them making the chance of the ball bouncing to the right 100%, my question is, What is the chance that the ball will end up in hole #2 if there is two different ways the ball can end there with different chances?

I personally calculated 43.75 %, but that was using subtraction of probabilities which can prove to be super situational so I wish to know a better method for this kind of problems

Hole #4 : 12.5%_______ Hole #3 : 18.75% (The logic was that without the wall Hole #3 and #2 share a 37.5%)_______ Hole #2 : 43.75% (Maybe ? I realised it's also the median between the two chances 50% in method one and 37.5% in method two)_______ Hole #1 : 25%

Here is the formula I used (n was not a constant)

I just learned probability yesterday so my methods can be basic or down right stupid.

Thank you for taking your precious time to help me.

> [image: Formula used]

Comment: Each individual path is taken with the product of the probabilities to branch to the left or right. At hole #2 we arrive via two paths which gives us the probability $0.5^2+0.5^3=0.375\,.$ Can you proceed?

Comment: It might be better to just compute the probabilites of each the bottom obstacles. Should be straightforward from there.